# Why is jQuery parent().index() not working when used in jQuery widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-widgets

I am creating a jQuery widget.
I have this code example set up to match my original situation as closely as possible...

```
function someFunction(){
$("#somediv").on("click", ".rem", $.proxy(this.handleEvent, this));
}

function handleEvent(that){
    var testval = $(that).parent().index();
   console.log(testval);
}

someFunction();
```

JSBin here ----> http://jsbin.com/cewevo/

The issue is that, regardless of the 'X' button clicked on, the index result is '-1'.
I have tried every element path I can think of, but the best I can do is get the innerText of the related button click.  I need the index so that I can delete the correct element in the original array that was used to populate the list.

Code like this works as expected, except the lines below does not work for me in the widget context.

```
  $("somediv").on("click", ".rem", function(){
    var testval = $(this).parent().index();
});
```

I am using the .proxy function to try to get the right context to the function "handleEvent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that using `$.proxy` is the best option here since, in your case `handleEvent` always receives the mouse event as argument.

The following code gives the result that you want.

```
function someFunction(){
    $("#somediv").on("click", ".rem", $.proxy(this.handleEvent));
}

function handleEvent(that){
    var testval = $(that.target).parent().index();
    console.log(testval);
}
```

Comment: It may be that using 'that.target' in the selector part of the jQuery was most of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code so it behaves how you are expecting:

```
function someFunction(){
$("#somediv").on("click", ".rem", function() { 
      $.proxy(handleEvent, this)();
    });
}

function handleEvent(){
   var testval = $(this).parent().index();
   console.log(testval);

}

someFunction();
```

They key here is to wrap `$.proxy` inside a `function()`. It wasn't working as expected because the context was wrong. Without the inner function, `this` inside of `$.proxy` was referring to jQuery itself, and not the jQuery object that was clicked on. The function parameter to `on` reccieves the clicked element as its context.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over complicating it.

http://jsbin.com/kekadubeca/2/

just add a class on the UL so it's a bit easier to call and viola

```
var items = $('.myUl li').click(function() {
    console.log(items.index(this));

});
```

Comment: thanks for this solution, the idea of adding the class to the UL is something I totally did not think of.  However, in my case, I already have a bunch of divs and classes, and I am trying to minimize adding additional divs/classes.

Comment: @BillH you dont have to add the class, it just makes it so you can directly call it